# looping through elasticsearch queryresult using Mpdreamz/NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Iam using Mpdreamz/NEST  as .net client for searching elasticsearch.

I am getting the result count of search result using `result.Hits.Total`. But I am wondering how I can display the value of a field from the result.

Comment: Please give answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624786/display-elastic-search-hits-values-using-nest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var result = client.Search(....)`

Will return a a `QueryResult<dynamic>` with a `Documents` property of type `IEnumerable<dynamic>` You can loop over this like so:

```
foreach(var d in result.Documents)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.title);
}
```

The casing matters here `d.Title` will result in a RuntimeBinderException. Unless your elasticsearch field actually exactly matches 'Title`

You can also map to POCO's

```
public class MyResult
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

...

`var result = client.Search<MyResult>(....)`

Now `Documents` is a `IEnumerable<MyResult>` which will give you compile time guarantees the property exists.

You should not have to access `.Fields["field"]` unless you are dealing with user input.

`result.Total` is also preferred over `result.Hits.Total`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at NEST source code, it seems that you could do something like:

```
foreach (var item in result.Documents.ToList())
{
    string msg = "Name: " + item.Name + " | Value: " + item.Text;
    alert(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply .. I tried this but I want to display the value of a single field from the result,say "title".  var result = client.Search(s => s
                        .Index("algotest")... 
                           .MatchAll()                                            
                    );  this is my search query .

Comment: EXCEPTION: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   getting this exception when using string Title = res.Fields["title"];

Comment: Seems that the `res` object is `null` then. Can you provide more code of your application?

Comment: getting the same exception with the second loop also :(  My code for dispalying title is attaching in gist please check .One more thing the search result returned total 32 hits  then how res becomes null!!! https://gist.github.com/3434337

Comment: yes it works :) Thank you very much Yannick  for your great help