# Display elastic search hits values using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using following code for searching the articleid and control fields. it will hold the 2 fields values. But I can't access these two fields values.
HERE search<> is dynamic.

```cs
  var searchrange = _client.Search<dynamic>(s =>  s
               .Indices("kb_v2").Types("kb")
               .From(0).Size(10)
               .Fields("articleid","control")
               .Query(q => q
                     .Range(r =>r
                         .OnField("articleid")
                         .Greater("2")
                         .Lower("5"))));
```

can you explain How to get the this two fields values..

Answer (score 1):

Since Elasticsearch 1.0 fields are always returned as a `Dictionary<string, object[]>` on hits to access these in NEST you can use:

```
foreach (var doc in queryResults.FieldSelections)
{
    var articleIds = doc.FieldValues<int[]>("articleid");
}
```

See [this PR](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/pull/619) for more details on the syntax.

Comment: Its working. i have another one doubt. if i using **QueryResult.Hits** means,we will get keys and values.. how can access the keys and corresponding keys values ??

Comment: Then using doc.FieldValues<>() method fields are always returned as array except for internal metadata values (for example "_id" will be returned as single value).

Answer (score 0):

The search response (`ISearchResponse` type) has a FieldSelections property which holds the results and details. With the older version of Nest, one had to loop over the Hits property to find the value of each field.

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "kb_v2",
            "_type": "kb",
            "_id": "3565178",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "articleid": [
                  "3"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "kb_v2",
            "_type": "kb",
            "_id": "3932480",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "articleid": [
                  "4"
               ]
            }
         }]
```

More on how to use the FieldSelections in ElastichSearch.net client is mentioned in this Unit test [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Integration/Search/FieldTests/FieldsTest.cs)

Comment: this is option contain the index, type, id ,score and fields values.. i am asking firstname annd john values only.

Comment: Index, type, id metadata will be part of any response from elasticsearch, you need to make use of FieldSelections property that has Key as `articleid` and expected value response object in Nest API.

Comment: i am using this code for get the article id and control value using for loop  foreach (var m in searchrange.Hits)
             {var titl=m.Fields.FieldValuesDictionary.TryGetValue("articleid",out dynamic);} 

But I couldn't get the article value..

Comment: Which version of Nest and elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: elastic search 1.2.1 and Nest v4.0.30319